# force disconnect from server side sockjs node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockjs

How can I force disconnect a connection from the server side using sockjs?
I've had a good look at the home page but no luck.
I image it is something like (but this is an unknown method):

```
    socket.close();
```

It's been almost a year since I wrote the basis of my sockjs project, and going back to the lower level again I can't even find where my old code like 'server.close()' is specified, where is the documentation gone? (with respect to the question of closing a specific client)

Answer (score 1):

Do apologize, I had the socket defined but unusable, my own fault.

some_user_socket.close(); works perfectly fine from the server side.